# DNS not resolving correctly for my domain name

Tags: domain-name-system

My domain name is not resolving correctly.  It should resolve correctly to an IP address provided by my cable company.  That address is dynamic.  I run an app that updates the nameserver hosted at everydns.net.  I look at my router's admin page and I see that my external address is a.b.c.d  Yet my domain name is not resolving to this address.

At my domain name registrar, the DNS point to everydns.net (NS1.EVERYDNS.NET, NS2.EVERYDNS.NET, etc).  At my everydns.net console, I see that my DNS A record is a.b.c.d, which is what it should be.

BUT when I do nslookup on my domain, it returns and answer of w.x.y.z.  Even when I do a nslookup specifying the nameserver of everydns, it return w.x.y.x!  I expected it to return a.b.c.d.  How could this be?

Comment: You'll probably want to provide your domain and host names if you want debugging assistance.  We can then look at the DNS records and tell you what is wrong.  I assume you want your domain's @ record to point at your dynamic home/cable IP?  You'll need to either update each time your IP changes, or you might want to use a dyndns service instead.

Comment: @mfarver, yes i use an app that runs every day to update the DNS record with my cable IP address.  I've verified that the DNS A record is pointing to my home IP.  Is there anything else I should check?  Everything seems to be in order yet the resolution is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I'm not getting any response from ns1.everydns.net or ns2.everydns.net.

It seems EveryDNS was taken over by DynDNS. Maybe they are discontinuing some old services in the belief that everyone transitioned to the DynDNS branded service? Maybe they are just having technical problems?

I would contact support@everydns.com and then DynDNS support.

Comment: I tried "nslookup mydomain.com ns2.everydns.net" and it's returning the expected IP.  So things are working correctly again.  Not sure what happened.  Must be something on everydns's side.